# Java program that deals with arrays specifically finding a value greater than the limit

Tags: java, arrays

Write a program that does the following:

1. Ask the user to enter 10 integers (to fill the array).
2. Ask the user to enter a number, representing a limit.
3. Call a method that displays all values that are greater than the limit.

   3a. Your method should accept the array and the limit as formal parameters.

   3b. The method does not return a value, but outputs the values that are greater than the limit values (Note: the output could be blank if the limit value is too large).

What I have done so far:

```java
import java.util.scanner;

public class Array {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System. in );
        double[] list2 = new double[10];
        System.out.println("Enter 10 double values");
        int i = 0;
        while (i < list2.length) {
            list2[i] = input.nextDouble();
            i++;
        }
        System.out.println("The average is " + average(list2));
    }

    public static double average(double[] array) {
        double sum = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
        sum += array[i];
        return sum / array.length;
    }
}
```

Comment: What is wrong with what you have?

Comment: This program finds the average, however the end result should look like this:                                                 Please enter 10 numbers: 23 16 47 14 8 6 35 89 28 7.
Please enter a limit: 34.
47 35 89 are greater than the limit 34.

Answer (score 0):

This is a basic method:

```
double[] aboveLimit = new double[list2.length];
double limit; //set limit variable
int j = 0;
for(int i = 0;i < list2.length;i++) {
  if(list2[i] > limit) {
    aboveLimit[j] = list2[i];
    j++;
  }
}

for(int i = 0;i < aboveLimit.length;i++) { //checks when reached end of all numbers
    if(aboveLimit[i] == 0) {
        if(i == 0) {
            break; //if there are no numebrs greater than the limit, nothing happens
        }
        else {
            System.out.println(" are above the limit.");
            break;
        }
    }
    else {
        System.out.println(aboveLimit[i] + ", ");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You just have to create a new `array` which will store all value, if any, that are greater than `limit`. Then by the counter `j` you can find out if some values are greater or not because counter `j` will only increment if there are some greater values:

Working code it includes your average method also:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class stackArray 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System. in );
        double[] list2 = new double[10];
        double limit;
        System.out.println("Enter 10 double values");
        int i = 0;
        while (i < list2.length) 
        {
            list2[i] = input.nextDouble();
            i++;
        }
        System.out.println("The average is " + average(list2));
        System.out.print("\nEnter Limit: ");
        limit = input.nextDouble();
        findGreater(list2,limit);
    }

   public static void findGreater(double [] array, double limit)
   {
        double[] greater = new double[array.length];  // new array to save all the greater value
        int j = 0; // index to add value in Greater array
        for(int i = 0;i < array.length;i++) 
        {
            if(array[i] > limit) 
            {
                greater[j] = array[i];
                j++;
            }
        }

        if(j!=0)  //if J!=0 it means there is some value thats why J is incremneted in above FOR Loop
        {           
            System.out.printf("\nValue above %.2f are: ", limit);
            for(int i = 0;i < j;i++) 
            {
                System.out.printf(greater[i] + " ");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.printf("\nNo vlaue is above %.2f", limit);
        }

   }

    public static double average(double[] array) 
    {
        double sum = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
            sum += array[i];
        return sum / array.length;
    }
}
```